# Japanese job and UK taxes

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, japan

I am a Japanese national working freelance for a Japanese company and for personal reasons I will move permanently to the UK on November 13th this year. The Japanese company will let me do freelance work for them even after I move to the UK. I plan to work for them only until I find a stable fully UK-based job.
For this, I will have a monthly income which will be over the £2000 allowance, but I do not plan to transfer it to my UK bank account.
I read the articles about the foreign income taxation but I am still not sure what I should do. I was told by my current company that I will not pay the taxes in Japan.

Comment: Hello, to be clear, which "allowance" are you referring to in sentence 4?  Thanks.

Comment: Hello, with "allowance" I am referring to this: https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/paying-tax . I guess I must pay tax on foreign income, as I will get my salary every month.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will just freelance as a self-employed "sole trader" and don't intend to set yourself up as a limited company:

You should follow the guidance for the self-employed here: https://www.gov.uk/working-for-yourself and https://www.gov.uk/set-up-sole-trader

That'll probably include registering for self-assessment with HMRC.

It should not matter that the income is from foreign sources and/or paid into/retained in a foreign bank.  So far as HMRC is concerned, for the purposes of assessing tax liability "you would just convert this income into pounds sterling and add this to your turnover." ([source](https://community.hmrc.gov.uk/forums/customerforums/sa/2b0b3f72-71cd-e911-b3b9-00155d9c6b78)); however as that notes: if tax is deducted in the foreign payer's country you might also need to fill out the "foreign section" of the tax return to avoid double taxation.